# How to pass tuple and variable as args

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, python-multithreading

I need to pass a large tuple and a single variable into a threaded task as arguments.

```
excelbtn_text.set("Outputting...")
excelClass = excelCL()
excel_thread = threading.Thread(target=excelClass.excelOut, args=(dcf_data_tuple, excelbtn_text))
excel_thread.daemon = True
excel_thread.start()
```

However I receive an error, `TypeError: excelOut() missing 242 required positional arguments`. Is there anyway I can get past this problem?

The error never occurred while I was only passing the tuple as an argument.

Comment: your explanation is a little bit confused, some more information will be useful (`excelOut()` code? code working?...). I also think that you missed a `=` between `args` and `(dfc_data...`

Comment: The tuple contains about 241 lists of information that go into an excel spreadsheet. Using just `args=(dcf_data_tuple)` worked, however adding the `excelbtn_text` variable to the args seemed to break the tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to pass a tuple and another value, you can just make another tuple with two members—the big tuple, and the other value. Exactly as you're doing:

```
args=(dcf_data_tuple, excelbtn_text)
```

But the arguments you pass have to match the method's function definition. Passing a valid tuple of 2 values as the arguments for a method doesn't work unless that method takes 2 parameters.

---

To resolve your confusion, first, this does not mean what you think it does:

```
args=(dcf_data_tuple)
```

Parentheses do not create a tuple; commas create a tuple. In other words, `(2)` is not a 1-element tuple containing the number `2`, it's just the number `2`. And `(dct_data_tuple)` is not a 1-element tuple containing the tuple `dct_data_tuple`, it's just `dct_data_tuple`.

So, the function definition for `excelClass.excelOut` is presumably taking *not* a single giant tuple as a parameter, but rather hundreds of separate parameters.

This is a bizarre design, but it's not actually illegal.

And that matches the exception you're getting: when you pass it 2 arguments (the first of which is a giant tuple), rather than hundreds arguments, it complains that you're missing 242 positional arguments:

> TypeError: excelOut() missing 242 required positional arguments

---

The simplest way to fix this is to give `excelOut` a reasonable signature that matches what you want to pass it:

```
def excelOut(self, data_tuple, text):
    # do stuff here
```

If you for some reason can't change its definition, then you have to look at what the definition is, and try to match it. If, for example, it looks like this:

```
def excelOut(self, data0, data1, … hundreds more, …, text):
```

… then you have to call it like this:

```
args=dcf_data_tuple + (excelbtn_text,)
```

Notice the comma at the end. That means `(excelbtn_text,)` is a 1-element tuple. And then we add the giant tuple to the 1-element tuple and get back a giant-plus-1-element tuple, which now matches the method's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you can add an asterisk before your tuple to pass the arguments unwrapped:

```
excelbtn_text.set("Outputting...")
excelClass = excelCL()
excel_thread = threading.Thread(target=excelClass.excelOut, args=(*dcf_data_tuple, excelbtn_text))
excel_thread.daemon = True
excel_thread.start()
```